# TypeScript overload and generics

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1, typescript2.2

I do have this class:

```
class Container<T>
{
    prop<K extends keyof T>(key: K): BehaviorSubject<T[K]>
    {
        return null;    // something
    }

    obj<K extends keyof T>(key: K): Container<T[K]>
    {
        return null;    // something
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
interface Obj
{
    id: number;

    employee: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }
}

let container: Container<Obj>;
let id = container.prop('id');  // BehaviorSubject<number>
let employee = container.obj('employee');   // Container<{ id: number; name: string; }
let employeeName = employee.prop('name');   // BehaviorSubject<string>
```

Now I want the same thing (type of variables commented above) but I'd like to use the same function name for prop and obj. I want a overload that switchs the returned type base on the property type.

Is it possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Can you also provide a code example of how you'd **like** to use the function (after the two `prop` and `obj` functions have been merged)?

Comment: That will be the job of a class that inspect things dynamically. I want just a way to map this to static types.

Comment: But both functions expect the same argument, how would you differentiate between the two?

Comment: The object will be pre-created and the functions will just return the properties. It happens that the pre-created data matches these types that I want.

Comment: I had submited a feature request to TypeScript to implement a elegant (IMHO) way to do this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13214

Comment: You can just use this `Deferred<T>` of yours, there's nothing that needs to be added to typescript. But I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish in this question. Can you please add to your question some code explaining it and/or how you would be using it?

Comment: No Deferred could not be used for what I want nor it can nest on children objects. Based on a type with embedded objects and arrays, I want to tranform only leaf properties (the non-arrays / non-objects) to BehaviorSubject<T>. JavaScript is JavaScript and I can do this dynamically, but I want to map the dynamically generated object to use types.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you then you can do something like this:

```
class Container<T> {
    private value: T;

    ...

    get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): Container<T[K]> | BehaviorSubject<T[K]> {
        let value = this.value[key];

        if (typeof value === "number" || typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "boolean") {
            // return a BehaviorSubject
        } else {
            // return a Container
        }
    }
}
```

The problem will be of course when using this `Container.get`, you'll need to type assert:

```
let id = container.get("id") as BehaviorSubject<number>;
let employee = container.obj("employee") as Container<{ id: number; name: string; };
```

Comment: I want the thing without type asserts nor having extra properties (with intersection types). I tried it with overloaded functions with extra parameters and default values but could not achieve too.

Comment: You can not have different signatures if they all have the same exact args (in this case `key: K`), there's no way around that. And you can't do without the type assertion because the information about which type it is is only available inside the function body.  You better just stick with the two methods.